# How to test this method

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

```
public AbonnementControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController) {
        this.stdSetController = standardSetController;
        this.subscriptionIds = new List<Id>();
        for (sObject obj : standardSetController.getSelected()) {
            this.subscriptionIds.add(obj.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing too special about StandardSetControllers. You test it the same way you test everything else.

1. Set up test data
2. Execute the method you want to stress
3. Gather results, and make assertions to verify that your code behaves the way you think it should

The part that most people won't be familiar with here is how to prepare an instance of `ApexPages.StandardSetController`. Your first stop to figure that out should probably be [the official documentation on StandardSetController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm)

From there, we see that you simply pass in a `List<SObject>` to the constructor.

```
List<Account> myAccountsList = new List<Account>();

// test data generation omitted

insert myAccountsList;

ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(myAccountsList);
```

Now that's all well and good, and would be sufficient for a test method that stresses what happens when no records are selected (which is definitely a test method you should have). How do we make one (or more) of the records "selected" though?

Again, [documentation to the rescue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm). Looking through the list of StandardSetController methods, you'll see there's a `setSelected()` method.

It takes a `List<SObject>`, simple enough.

```
List<Account> myAccountsList = new List<Account>();

// test data generation omitted

insert myAccountsList;

ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(myAccountsList);

// Set some selected records for the test
// A List<Account> is all that's really required, but using a Map instead
//   should help make it easier to make assertions about which record Ids
//   were marked as "selected"
new Map<Id, Account> selectedMap = new Map<Id, Account>(new List<Account>{
    myAccountsList[0],
    myAccountsList[2]
});

stdSetCon.setSelected(selectedMap.values());
```